# charging current of lead acid battery

Tags: battery-charging

I would like to use my homemade battery charger, rated 15VDC 7A, to charge a 25Ah lead acid battery. Would there be an easy way to limit the charging current to 2.5A (Ah/10)?

Comment: modify the charger. my battery charger uses SCRs in half the rectifier and the SCRs control the charge rate.

Comment: You'll need to advise the brand and model of charger. It is unlikely to be practical to do this. A smaller appropriate charger is a better choice. You could add a 2.5A constant current source. You could modify the circuitry.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to use my homemade battery charger, rated 15VDC 7A, to charge a 25Ah lead acid battery. Would there be an easy way to limit the charging current to 2.5A (Ah/10)?

As you did your own battery charger, if done with analog electronics, you might have done as a 1, 2 or 3 stage charger, as I will explain further ahead.

But to answer your question, **yes** there are some ways to limit the charging current - crucial for “bulk charging” mode:

- As you did your own charger, you might already have a current limiting circuit, usually included to protect the series pass power transistor. In this case, recalculate the shunt resistor and switch
  to this larger value to further limit the current.
- Another way, very simple and non-invasive to your charger would be to *use a series resistor between the charger (positive) and the battery (positive) to further limit the charging current*. A few *incandescent lamps, as used in the cars, rated as 10W or 21W*, can be joined in parallel until the desired current passes to the battery. Incandescent lamps are great non-linear (non ohmic) resistors, maintaining the current less dependent of their voltage drop - if you allow an heresy, it would be a poor man’s “constant” current circuit.

As a reminder, these are the 3 stages or modes applicable for normal charging of lead acid batteries:

1. **Bulk mode:** Charging current is limited up to a “safe“ value, while the battery voltage increases. It is a constant current (CC) mode. When current starts to reduce, the battery is charged at aprox. 80% of rated capacity.
2. **Absorption mode:** When the battery voltage reaches the “absorption charging voltage”, it enters the absorption mode, operating in constant voltage mode, *typically at 14.4V (@ 25°C)*. Depending of literature sources bulk mode shifts to the next mode when the charging current reduces to about 10% to 20% of bulk current value or 3% to 5% of AH. At this point, battery would be fully charged (100%).
3. **Floating mode:** The constant voltage mode value is lowered to the “floating charging mode”, *typically at 13.8V*. It can be maintained for extended periods (days) without overcharging the battery, but for that, the precise value should be fine tuned for existing ambient/battery temperature.

**Additional information about how to charge**, or when the absorption charging mode should be terminated?

The recommended current for bulk charging (first mode) is 10% of rated AH. Some articles and manufacturers cite up to 20% as maximum to be considered still within “slow charging” class.

References:

[Recommended charging for lead acid batteries - Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/index.php/learn/article/charging_the_lead_acid_battery)

[Chargetek’s charging and equalization - additional information](https://chargetek.com/images/pdfs/equal.pdf)